# Justify text in table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, text-align

I have a Table with 2 columns.I would like to be able to justify text in each cell so i used  `text-align:justify;` for each `<td>` tag,but it does not seem to work?

[image]

**Html Code:**

```
<table >
<tr >
<td  class=tblcellA>سرآغاز گفتار نام خداست </td>
<td  class=tblcellB>كه رحمتگر و مهربان خلق راست</td>   
</tr>
<tr >
<td  class=tblcellA>ستايش بود ويژه كردگار</td>
<td  class=tblcellB>كه بر عالمين است پروردگار</td>   
</tr>
</table>
```

**Css Code:**

```
body
{
   overflow:hidden;
   font-family:tahoma;
   FONT-SIZE:15px;
direction:rtl;
}
.tblcellA
{
    BORDER-RIGHT: #7e975b 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #7e975b 1px solid;
    BORDER-LEFT: #7e975b 1px solid;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #7e975b 1px solid;

   text-align:justify;
   padding-right:18px;
    width:230px;

}
.tblcellB
{
    BORDER-RIGHT: #7e975b 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #7e975b 1px solid;
    BORDER-LEFT: #7e975b 1px solid;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #7e975b 1px solid;

   width:230px;
   text-align:justify;
   padding-right:18px;
}
```

**Result:**
http://jsfiddle.net/d5VTg/22/

How can I justify this line of text?
​
​

Comment: Do you need that cell to be filled with text?? without space?? coz now your text is justified only

Comment: @Sowmya Shivaram:Yes I need each cells fill  with text and with space between words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fixed the width of the each cell so that you are able see the extra white space. Otherwise your text is justified.

In this case change the width properties like this

```
width:auto;
max-width:230px;
```

Now the cell max width will be 230px

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d5VTg/42/)

Comment: this answer does not appear to work .. maybe "not anymore" .. see the ::after trick with width:100% to achieve the desired effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21199162/3022387