# Force single line of text in element to fill width with CSS

Tags: html, css, text

I have a `div` element that holds one line of text. How can I get this text to fill the width 100%?

`text-align:justify` is only working on elements with several lines of text, and has no effect on the `div` with single line. Manually adjusting the letter-spacing and word-spacing is ugly and ineffective.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: The conventional way to solve this is to use an `:after` pseudo element to generate enough content to make the content flow onto a second line, then tinker with font-size, line-height, height, and overflow to hide the extra vertical space that this causes.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div {
  text-align: justify;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some sample testing string
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4Y2u/)

Take a look [here](http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/css/css-displaying-a-justified-line-of-text.html) for more info.

Comment: Using that trick to justify a oneliner title, I had to force the height of my element to prevent it for adding a new empty line under my title.

Comment: @svassr or you can also add a ::before pseudo element and then just tweak the line-height on the parent element, this way the text being always centered between the two pseudo elements. All in all, nice solution @mutil!

Answer (score 3):

The modern way to do this is with [`text-align-last: justify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last)