# How to justify text with letters from a to z in div in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have the list of letters from A to Z justified over the whole width of the div with class="col-md-12". Where do I have to add text-justify? I tried almost every location to put it.
Thanks Thorsten

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">             
        A, B, C, D, E, F, ... ,Z            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is never handy to start writting inmideatly in a column. You better add some element to write it in, such as a paragraph. You can add your justify class to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `A-Z` inside a paragraph and assign the bootstrap alignment class `text-justify` To occupy the full width of the div. You can set a pseudo-element :after that fakes a empty space/block after the paragraph. The `inline-block` will stretch the text to meet the content in the `:after` pseudo element.

Thanks for the hack: [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199057/css-force-single-line-of-text-in-element-to-fill-width) from Mutil

```css
p:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="text-justify">A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want your result to be?

Comment: That the list of letter spans from left to right over the whole width of the div class="col-md-12". But even with your solution it stays on the left side.

Comment: Glad it worked! :) If you are wondering why the scroll bar is appearing, you need to wrap the row inside a container.

Answer (score 1):

put the letters in `<p> /* here */ </p>` tag and set

```
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```