# CSS center any text with left alignment inside fixed size div

Tags: css, flexbox, center, vertical-alignment

I know a lot of methods to center an inner content but neither of them are working with custom size text with left alignment.

The result I want is http://joxi.ru/krDDq9duE6zL0r

Have tried all the known for me methods:

```
// first attempt
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

// second attempt
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

// third attempt
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

// forth attempt
.wrapper:after {
  content:'';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 74px;
}
```

Here's the code:

```css
.wrapper,
.wrapper2,
.wrapper3,
.wrapper4 {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 225px;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.try1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.try2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper3 {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.try4 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.wrapper4 {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper4:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 74px;
}

.try5 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<p>Tries:</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="try1">DUE DILIGENCE EXPIRATION</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="try2">DUE DILIGENCE EXPIRATION</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="try3">DUE DILIGENCE EXPIRATION</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper3">
  <div class="try4">DUE DILIGENCE EXPIRATION</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper4">
  <div class="try5">DUE DILIGENCE EXPIRATION</div>
</div>

<p>I want:</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="try1">DUE&nbsp;DILIGENCE EXPIRATION</div>
</div>
```

**UPD** 
Please notice, that the text could be any from one letter to multiple rows. So the inner content width is flexible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199057/force-single-line-of-text-in-element-to-fill-width-with-css

Comment: @Morpheus Tried to set justify on wrapper and content in the first case. The width of inner block doesn't expand.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vm8v2bx5/

Comment: @Morpheus 
This gap is definitely not a production behavior or the result I want http://joxi.ru/52aYnQoT4nqkN2

Answer (score 1):

Can you add `width` to child elements i.e to `.try1, .try2` and such if so then that can align child element to `center` of `parent div` using `CSS calc() function` as below,

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 225px;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper > .try1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(225px - 96px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="try1">DUE DILIGENCE EXPIRATION</div>
</div>
```

You can even check this using [flex](https://jsfiddle.net/se4p5c9h/).

Comment: Nice Suggestion 1 up from my side.

Comment: @frnt No, I can't. The width of inner content is flexible because it can contain any text. http://joxi.ru/L21bWjMS8JykpA

Comment: @frnt, the flex approach you provided not working either
https://jsfiddle.net/only_dimon/se4p5c9h/1/

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky Okay so you can't add width then remove that and change it's display to inline-block, as in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h75efskg/, https://jsfiddle.net/h75efskg/1/

Comment: @frnt The problem remains. The width of the container also is flexible.
The container can be any width, the text can be any size. The problem is that wrapping text takes more space then it is http://joxi.ru/Vm67abphDk8v02
See the updated fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/only_dimon/vwupq976/

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky Now even to fill that white-space which occurs when parent width increase then you have to include  word-break:break-all; in .try1 which will break your text formation at many points.

Comment: @frnt word-break isn't acceptable here. I thought maybe some flexbox magic can be used to center any text inside any container. But not I nor my collegues can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle also.
I have changed:
`position: fixed;`
`padding:padding: 0 51px;`

```
.wrapper4 {
  position: fixed;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 225px;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 0 51px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

See it live here: <kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4nn0hL0/1/)</kbd>

Comment: 1. You have changed the position to fixed which isn't suitable to most of cases.
2. You just changed horizontal padding but this doesn't solve the issue. I need 20px padding, the width of wrapper can be flexible, and the text can by other.